# Intersection of rectangles in java

Tags: java, sprite

I need to make the overlaps function to return true if any portion of the Sprite passed in as an argument overlaps the current Sprite. I thought about using rectangles, but I am looking for something more simple.

```
abstract class Sprite
{
private int x;
private int y;
private int size;
private int w;
private int h;
private int xSlope;
private int ySlope;
private Image image;
private static Random rand;

public Sprite(int xIn, int yIn, int width, int height, String imagePath, int imageSize) {
    if (rand == null) {
        rand = new Random();
    }
    size = imageSize;
    setImage(imagePath);
    x = xIn;
    y = yIn;
    w = width;
    h = height;
    xSlope = rand.nextInt(11) - 5;
    ySlope = rand.nextInt(11) - 5;
}

public int getX() { return x; }
public int getY() { return y; }
public int getSize() { return size; }
public void setSize(int s) { size = s; }
public void setX(int xIn) { x = xIn; }
public void setY(int yIn) { y = yIn; }

public void setImage(String imagePath) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to load image file.");
    }
}
public Image getImage() { return image; }

public boolean overlaps(Sprite s) {

}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(getImage(), x, y, getSize(), getSize(), null);
}

public void move() {
    // Move the Sprite
    int x = getX() + xSlope;
    int y = getY() + ySlope;
    if (x < 0) x = w;
    if (x > w) x = 0;
    if (y < 0) y = h;
    if (y > h) y = 0;
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that a `Sprite` represents a rectangle, and that both `Sprites` in question are AABB's (axis-aligned bounding boxes... a rectangle whose edges are parallel with the coordinate plane). If that's true, you can just check their position and their size.

(The following assumes that a positive Y signifies a downwards direction)

```
public boolean overlaps(Sprite s)
{
    return 
    (
        (this.getX() < s.getX()+s.getWidth())     && // check right side overlap
        (this.getX()+this.getWidth() > s.getX())  && // check left side overlap
        (this.getY() < s.getY()+s.getHeight())    && // check bottom side overlap
        (this.getY()+this.getHeight() > s.getY())    // check top side overlap
    );
}
```

This code works by using the Seperating Axis Theorem (SAT). The basic idea behind this is that you assume all sides are already overlapping. As soon as you  find a single side that doesn't overlap, that means the rectangles do not overlap, so you can return. You can read more about the SAT (as well as other methods of collision detection in 2D space) in [this fantastic tutorial](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) by Metanet software.

Comment: @pmartin8 I just worked through this on paper. My solution works even if `s` or `this` covers the other - it's effectively using the SAT for AABBs. You need to double check your logic.

Comment: The methods are trivial to add. `public int getWidth() { return w; }` and `public int getHeight() { return h; }`. And identical rectangles in the same location with the same width and height WILL return true.

Comment: Oh very sorry Nik, I got it all wrong. It does work. Sorry again :)

Answer (score -2):

Look at https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html#overlaps-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle-

```
com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersectoroverlaps(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
```

I think you want to know if both rectangle 'intersect', right??

Comment: This would require the poster to use a third party library for a single function - hardly an appropriate solution considering the logic to check for non-rotated rectangle overlap is relatively simple.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidePastore I was looking at what is a good answer On http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers. And I found out that what is really required is to point out exactly where the answer can be found in the referenced page. If you had looked at my link you would have seen that it references an API (unlikely to become down). The link targets the right method, so there is no information overload. While I appreciate the fact that you want to help SO, you might want ot be a bit more carefull when pasting this comment around.

Comment: With your edit, now it's more clear than before. Remember that everything could go down anytime. My comment is something auto generated by SO when you review the answers.

Comment: What if the API changes and the copy/paste in SO becomes out of synch with the library?